# Scatter plot with vertical lines - lollipop plot

Tags: r, plot, bioinformatics

I would like to build an scatter plot like this: http://www.cbioportal.org/public-portal/images/previews/tp53_mutations.png, in which each point has a circle + vertical line.

[image]

The closest thing I've found below, a 3D scatter plot from `library(scatterplot3d)`, but I just have x,y.

[image]

Do you have any suggestion of library/function/option to do so?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Also fairly easy in base graphics (the colored boxes below the y axis are a bit more tricky):

```
op <- par(ps=10)

par(mar=c(2, 3.5, 2, 1))
plot(x, y, ylim=c(-10, max(y)), t="n", axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE)
axis(1)
axis(2, at=pretty(c(0, max(y))))
mtext("# Mutations", side=2, line=2.5)
mtext("P53_Human", side=3, line=0.5, adj=0, font=2)
segments(x0=x, y0=y, y1=0, col=8)
points(x, y, pch=21, col=1, bg=2)

usr <- par()$usr
rect(usr[1], -8, usr[2], -1, col=8, border=NA)
rect(10, -10, 30, 1, col=rgb(0,1,0), border=rgb(0,0.8,0))
text(20, -5, label="P53", col="white")
rect(90, -10, 280, 1, col=rgb(1,0,0), border=rgb(0.8,0,0))
text(180, -5, label="P53", col="white")
rect(320, -10, 360, 1, col=rgb(0,0,1), border=rgb(0,0,0.8))
text(340, -5, label="P53", col="white")

par(op)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Simplest solution for just a circle & vertical line as asked:

```
vnum2 = runif(50, 0,1)
plot(1:50, vnum2)
segments(1:50, 0, 1:50, vnum2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using *ggplot2*, for example:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = disp, xend = disp, y = 0, yend = wt), data = mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes( x = disp, y = wt), colour = "red", size = 6, data = mtcars)
```

[image]